# List records in alphabetical order with headers in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm displaying a list of topics for an app written in CakePHP like so:

```
<ul>
    <?php foreach ($topics as $topic): ?>
        <li>
            <?php echo $topic['Topic']['title']; ?>
        </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

What I'd like to do is display them like:

```
<h3>A</h3>
<ul>
    <li>animals</li>
    <li>anger</li>
    <li>age</li>
</ul>

<h3>B</h3>
<ul>
    <li>bat</li>
    <li>bird</li>
</ul>

etc...
```

How would I do that? Bearing in mind that I could also have numbers e.g. 3d

ARRAY

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'Topic' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'title' => 'awesome'
        ),
        'TopicPost' => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                'id' => '1',
                'topic_id' => '1',
                'post_id' => '107'
            )
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'Topic' => array(
            'id' => '2',
            'title' => 'amazing'
        ),
        'TopicPost' => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                'id' => '2',
                'topic_id' => '2',
                'post_id' => '107'
            )
        )
    ),
    (int) 2 => array(
        'Topic' => array(
            'id' => '3',
            'title' => 'jazz'
        ),
        'TopicPost' => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                'id' => '3',
                'topic_id' => '3',
                'post_id' => '107'
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Are you sorting by the Topic or the Title?  Or are `A` and `B` the topic and `animals,anger,age` the title?

Comment: Nevermind, seems like you're sorting by the topic.  Hold on for an answer, writing one up.

Comment: A and B are ordering the topics. They're static. The topic and title is one and the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

My php is a bit rusty, so I apologise for possible errors, but the logic is hopefully clear. You can try this:

```
    <?php  
        $lastTopic = ' ';
        $first = true;
        $close = false;
        foreach ($topics as $topic): 
            $lastLetter = substr($lastTopic, 0, 1);
            $thisLetter = substr($topic['Topic']['title'], 0, 1);
            $isNewLetter =  $lastLetter == $thisLetter;
            if ($isNewLetter):
                $close = true;
                if($first) $first = false;
                else echo "</ul>";
    ?>
                <h3><?php echo $newLetter ?></h3>
                <ul>
                <?php endif; ?>
                    <li>
                        <?php 
                            echo $topic['Topic']['title']; 
                            $lastTopic = $topic['Topic']['title']; 
                        ?>
                    </li>

         <?php endforeach; ?>
         <?php if($close) echo "</ul>"; ?>
</ul>
```

The basic idea is that every time you encounter a topic starting with a new letter you close the html list and create a new header. This of course assumes that the list is already sorted.

Answer (score 0):

What you'll need to do is first create an array of sorted items which you can `foreach` through.  When you're building this array take the first letter of each topic and create a list of topics with the same letter or number.

### Given that `$topic` equals this:

```
$topic = array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'Topic' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'title' => 'awesome'
        ),
        'TopicPost' => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                'id' => '1',
                'topic_id' => '1',
                'post_id' => '107'
            )
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'Topic' => array(
            'id' => '2',
            'title' => 'amazing'
        ),
        'TopicPost' => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                'id' => '2',
                'topic_id' => '2',
                'post_id' => '107'
            )
        )
    ),
    (int) 2 => array(
        'Topic' => array(
            'id' => '3',
            'title' => 'jazz'
        ),
        'TopicPost' => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                'id' => '3',
                'topic_id' => '3',
                'post_id' => '107'
            )
        )
    )
);
```

### You can use the following code to process the array:

```
<?
foreach($topic as $currentTopic):
    $thisLetter = strtoupper($currentTopic['Topic']['title'][0]);
    $sorted[$thisLetter][] = $currentTopic['Topic']['title'];
    unset($thisLetter);
endforeach;

foreach($sorted as $key=>$value):

    echo '<h3>'.$key.'</h3>';
    echo '<ul>';

    foreach($value as $thisTopic):
        echo '<li>'.$thisTopic.'</li>';
    endforeach;

    echo '</ul>';

endforeach;
?>
```

This has been tested successfully.

Comment: displays id and title instead for the headers and just that. e.g I
id
T
title

Comment: I had to create my own array to replicate yours.  You may need to adjust that first foreach statement in order to correctly sort your array.

Comment: Well, unless you post the structure and values of that array it's hard for me to perfectly replicate your situation.

Comment: @Cameron - Try it now.  The code works, given that `$topic` is the variable which the array is held under.

Comment: Gives me the error: `Notice (8): Undefined index: Topic [APP/View/Topics/index.ctp, line 30]`

Comment: Bro, I've given you the chunk of code that you need to filter out that given array.  You're going to need to troubleshoot some of this on your end.  Can you paste what is at `line 30`?

Comment: Line 30 is this: `foreach($topic as $currentTopic):
    $thisLetter = strtoupper($currentTopic['Topic']['title'][0]);` so basically the first line of that code.

Comment: I don't think you're referencing the correct variable `$topic`.  Do you know how to write PHP or are you piecing things together?

Answer (score -1):

Try these codes:

```
<ul style="list-style-type:upper-alpha">
  <?php foreach ($topics as $topic): ?>
    <li>
        <?php echo $topic['Topic']['title']; ?>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: That's not what he wanted. Look at the question example again.